# How to display page breaks in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Is there a way to display page breaks (the horizontal dotted line) in Word 2007 within the Web Layout and Draft views? I am aware of the "Show all formatting marks" options, which isn't what I want as I don't want to see all the other formatting marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just looked for you for the past couple of minutes and been experimenting.

It looks like whilst you have the option to manually show various characters, a line break comes under "Show all formatting marks" which unfortunately for you means that you also see every other mark.

[image]

Sorry - I do not think this is possible.

Comment: this is correct for OLD documents. For new documents look at [answer by @user35384](http://superuser.com/a/135308/117002)

Answer (score 4):

That is simple.

To display page break go to the Home Ribbon. In the Paragraph group, click on the Show/Hide option. That is at the top right.

Answer (score 2):

In Word, go to "Options" -> "Advanced" -> At the bottom drop down "compatibility options" and select "all new documents" -> Expand layout options -> Check "Split apart page break and paragraph mark"

This will show page breaks in all new documents you create. You can also do the above individually for older documents you're working on.

Comment: this is correct - for all NEW documents. I have not managed to get it to work with previously created documents.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to be the best solution:

**OPTION ONE:**
As you want to only see the page breaks without formatting marks:

- Click on the "View" tab (top ribbon)
- On the far left is the "Document Views" section [- there are 5 options here: Print layout, Full Screen Reading, Web Layout, Outline & Draft.]

**CLICK ON "PRINT LAYOUT"**

(Do NOT select outline as mentioned above!)

You will now be able to see all of your page breaks without other formatting marks. breaks are shown as a blue space between pages rather than just a dotted line but hopefully that will meet your requirements. This works for ALL documents - new AND old.

---

**OPTION TWO: IF YOU ARE DEAD SET ON USING DRAFT LAYOUT OR WEB LAYOUT:**

Use the above-mentioned solution - Go to Home/windows button, and select Word Options from the bottom /right corner of the screen.

- Select "Advanced" tab (left column)
- Look to the right half of the screen - scroll down to the bottom of that screen.
- Select "Layout options" from the bottom of that screen.
- Partway down the screen is the option "Split apart page breaks & paragraph marks" (these options are listed in alphabetical order)
- Tick that option ("Split apart page breaks & paragraph marks"
- Click "OK"

**You should now see page breaks as a dotted horizontal line.**

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Simply click on the View tab and click Outline.  This will show your page breaks without all of your formatting.  When you are done simply switch back to Print Layout.